# In j meter test script why we exclude java script,cascade style sheet and include only html to check response time in performance test?

Tags: jmeter

While checking performance of public website why we exclude java scripts, style sheets and include only basic request which returns HTML file(host "www.test.com"  and "/" in path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude these scripts, styles and images only during **recording** of your test scenario with the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) as if you record these calls they will be captured, but when you replay them it will have nothing in common with that happens in the reality.

Real browsers act as follows:

- They download these scripts, images and styles when requesting the main page, but do it **in parallel** using several concurrent threads to speed up the process. So the main request forks into several sub-requests which are downloading all this stuff. In JMeter you can mimic this behaviour using "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" switch either in [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) or in [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)

  [image: Download Embedded resources]
- As you already know, browsers download scripts, images and styles and do it using several concurrent threads. The next point is that well-behaved browsers do it **only once**, on subsequent requests this stuff is being returned from the browser's cache. So you need to add a [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan to simulate this functionality representing browser cache and not overload the server
- Regarding 3-rd party content. If your web site uses scripts, images, videos, etc. from other domains - it is recommended to exclude these requests from your load testing scope as most likely you don't have any control of these 3-rd party content providers and won't be able to do anything even if the bottleneck is due to external server, your load test should focus solely on your application.

See [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide for more information on above hints and few more recommendations.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri . So in one script i need to have one request with embedded resources and in next request only HTML as rest of the request are getting cached  in same thread group to simulate actual user behavior .. Please correct my understanding .

Comment: Just add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager) to your Test Plan, it is smart enough to handle this for you. You need to consider a lot of things in order to properly simulate cache, i.e. [Etag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) header, [If-Modified-Since](https://varvy.com/ifmodified.html) header, etc. so don't make things overcompicated as the chance to make an error grows with the script complexity

Comment: Is there any way to avoid third party domain request which got retrevied along with domain under test(www.test.com) when "reterive embeded resources" option is checked. Also if I added IP address in host name I am seeing error in View Result tree.

Comment: It is, you can do it using `URLs must match` input on the [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)'s "Advanced" tab. Check out [Excluding Domains From The Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) for instructions and sample configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Because JMeter is only retrieving page elements, and does not execute javascript or render these components like real browsers do. Personally i like to retrieve all embedded resources to give myself a better understanding of the total load time, even if javascript is not executed/rendered.

You can also do a selective retrieval, or a full retrieval if you wish.
Use the checkbox named "retrieve embedded resources", or specify which elements should be retrieved. Getting full retrieval is also handy to see whether there are broken links to components in the page.